# Extract text from <li>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I extracted text from a blog, but in this format:

```
<li><b><a href="https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/article-id">Text</li>
```

I need to extract only text from it.

I tried this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
import nltk, re, pprint

def getAllDoxyDonkeyPosts(url,links):
    raw = request.urlopen(url).read()
    raw = BeautifulSoup(raw, "lxml")
    for a in raw.findAll('a'):
        try:
            url = a['href']
            title = a['title']
            if title == "Older Posts":
                links.append(url)
            getAllDoxyDonkeyPosts(url,links)
        except:
            title = ""
    return

blogUrl = "http://doxydonkey.blogspot.in/"
links = []
getAllDoxyDonkeyPosts(blogUrl,links)

def getDoxyDonkeyText(url):
    raw = request.urlopen(url).read()
    raw = BeautifulSoup(raw, "lxml")
    mydivs = raw.findAll("div", {"class":'post-body'}) 

    posts = []
    for div in mydivs:
        posts+=div.findAll("li")

return posts

doxyDonkeyPosts = []
for link in links:
    doxyDonkeyPosts+=getDoxyDonkeyText(link)


doxyDonkeyPosts
```

Comment: What have you tried? And don't use images like that. Remove the image and post it as text.

Comment: You've used the beautifulsoup tag, so you understood that's what you need. Therefore, please show how far you've gotten using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
t = '<li><b><a href = "www.google.com">Google</a></b></li>'

b = BeautifulSoup(t, "html.parser")
print b.text #--> Google
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I needed

Comment: @Ketochka please accept the answer to close the question